# How to pass selected multiselect picklist and pageblock table values from one vf page to another

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a multiselect picklist and pageblock table in a visualforce page i want to send the selected multiselect picklist value and modified page block table value to the next visualforce page

This is my vf page code

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter based on profiles" collapsible="true" >
                   <apex:selectList style="margin-left: 60%;width:150%"  value="{!multival}" size="10" multiselect="true" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList> 
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:commandButton style="margin-left: 30%;width:5%" value="Next" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

This is my first controller code

```
 public String multival {get;set;}
 public pagereference redirect(){ 
    PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/nextPage? 
 att='+multival);
    redirect.setRedirect(true);
    return redirect;      

}
```

This is my second controller code

```
public class selectedList {
 public String multival {get;set;}
    public selectedList (){
         multival = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('att');
    }
}
```

How do i pass the selected multiselect picklist value to my nextpage?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same controller on your second vf page. You can redirect to the second page, but if its using the same controller, you can access all variable values.

See here for creating a visualforce wizard:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm